# Ethernet link not detected under Linux 3.6.9, but is ok in 2.6.39

Tags: linux, ethernet

I have a custom Linux appliance with a 100M ethernet port.  Under the 2.6.39 kernel, networking was never an issue.  Autonegotiation worked just fine, as did network transfers.  Now, with the newer 3.6.9 kernel the vast majority of the devices either say no link, or are limited to 10M/half dulpex (which doesn't actually work at all).

My suspicion is that there's a problem in the design of the ehternet adapter, and that the newer kernel is checking for things the older kernel ignored.  My question is, does anyone know what fundamental driver changes happened between releases?  I'd like to get this running again, but I don't know that I can possibly fix the hardware at this point, so I'm looking for a software work around.  I've tried turning off autonegotiation, and setting the link speed manually, but there's still no carrier detected, so that doesn't seem to have an effect.

Any ideas are welcome.

The ethernet controller is integrated into my ARM SoC.  I'm using an Atmel AT91SAM9X25 microprocessor, which has a Davicom DM9161A PHY driver.  It looks like the PHY sub system isn't detecting that there's a link on the port.

The output from dmesg looks like this:

```
macb f802c000.ethernet: (unregistered net_device): invalid hw address, using random
libphy: MACB_mii_bus: probed
macb f802c000.ethernet: eth0: Cadence MACB at 0xf802c000 irq 24 (e6:0d:5b:9d:13:c8)
macb f802c000.ethernet: eth0: attached PHY driver [Davicom DM9161A] (mii_bus:phy_addr=f802c000.etherne:1f, irq=-1)
IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
```

(There are a couple of units where the link does actually come up, but nearly all of them never move past the link is not ready state.  100% of them worked correctly under the older kernel.)

Thanks for your replies.

Comment: What network chipset does the appliance have?

Comment: You really need to add more details if you want assistance.

Comment: Check `dmesg` for Ethernet-related messages